# Does Google Analytics Destination Goal Tracking match query params?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm investigating Google Analtyics Goal tracking.  I would like to append a query param to specific urls to indicate goal completion.   Eg.

```
/some/path?goal=goal_name
```

I do not want to use the path part of the url for matching, only the query param.  If I setup a destination regex matcher, will Google Analytics match the param part of the url?  Eg.

```
goal=goal_name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does. If you use regexp as match type remember to escape your question mark if you use the full url (i.e. `/some/path\?goal=goal_name`).

You can actually test this easily - the realtime reports have a "conversion" menu item that shows goal conversions immediately (not e-commerce-transactions, though). I usually create a separate view to test new goals and filters so I don't mess up my live data - I recommend you do the same.